# Python tar using shell not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, tar

I'm tryting to tar some files with the following pattern:

```
/var/lib/cassandra/data/*/*/snapshots/<snapid>/
```

If I execute the tar command manually, it works without problem but when I execute it using python, it fails.

I execute it as follows:

```
    output = subprocess.check_output(["tar","cf", outputfile, snappath])
```

But while I get the following error, I could tar the file manually

```
tar: /var/lib/cassandra/data/*/*/snapshots/20151215104608: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./cassandrabackup2s3.py", line 68, in <module>
    create_snapshot_file(snapid)
  File "./cassandrabackup2s3.py", line 46, in create_snapshot_file
    output = subprocess.check_output(["tar","cf", outputfile, snappath])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 575, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['tar', 'cf', '/tmp/20151215104608.tgz', '/var/lib/cassandra/data/*/*/snapshots/20151215104608/']' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

I saw a few posts about removing "`-`" from `-cvzf` or use shell=True but nothing works. Here is the output using `Shell=True`

```
 output = subprocess.check_output(["tar","cf", outputfile, snappath], shell=True)
```

Seems that sintax of tar is incorect:

```
tar: You must specify one of the `-Acdtrux' or `--test-label'  options
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./cassandrabackup2s3.py", line 68, in <module>
    create_snapshot_file(snapid)
  File "./cassandrabackup2s3.py", line 46, in create_snapshot_file
    output = subprocess.check_output(["tar","cf", outputfile, snappath], shell=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 575, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['tar', 'cf', '/tmp/20151215103816.tgz', '/var/lib/cassandra/data/*/*/snapshots/20151215103816/']' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

I have tried using tar library but it seems regex like `*` doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried escaping astrix? Like \ *

Comment: It doesn't work because the arguments are passed literally from the output using subprocess: `tar: /var/lib/cassandra/data/\\*/\\*/snapshots/20151215111922: Cannot stat: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run this command at the shell prompt, the shell expands the wildcards.  If you want Python to do wildcard expansion, you have to ask for it separately.

It's not clear from your question which part isn't working, but I guess you want

```
cmd = ['tar', 'cf', outputfile]
cmd.extend(glob.glob(snappath))
output = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
```

Adding `shell=True` would have fixed your problem if you had not used a list of arguments to `subprocess`; then the shell would have parsed the string and performed wildcard expansion.  But when you supply a list, `shell=True` does nothing, because you (are assumed to) have already performed the command-line parsing which the shell would perform.  But generally, if your needs are simple, you should avoid `shell=True` anyway, as the shell itself introduces a number of complications which you need to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use tarfile library instead: https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html

Edited to give you the example:

```
import glob
import tarfile
snaps = glob.glob("/var/lib/cassandra/data/*/*/snapshots/<snapid>/")
with tarfile.open("tared.tar","w") as tar:
    for snap in snaps:
         tar.add(snap)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run `tar` on the command-line, then the path:

```
/var/lib/cassandra/data/*/*/snapshots/<snapid>/
```

Is expanded by the **shell**, not by the `tar` command. `check_output` will not do that `*` expansion, so you're right that you need `shell=True` so that a shell exists to expand those variables.

However, to use a shell, you should give subprocess functions a string, not a list:

```
output = subprocess.check_output("echo my command is here", shell=True)
```

So your tar command, moved to two separate lines for clarity:

```
command = "tar cf {} {}".format(outputfile, snappath)
output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
```

As @radek says, you can also use the tar module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html

Comment: Try to avoid `shell=True` if you can.  The shell is overkill for the simple feature of adding a glob expansion.

Comment: I agree, but I try to follow the working people post in the question, to make sure there are the smallest number of conceptual leaps between what they're doing and the explanation they're getting.